# android: load button background image from web via Picasso

Tags: android, imageview, android-button, picasso

How can i use Picasso library to load image from web to button background image ? is it possible ? i use this code to load image on imageView

```
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(imageView);
```

But i dont know how to use this library with button view.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class MyButton extends Button implements Target {

    public MyButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr, int defStyleRes) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapLoaded(Bitmap bitmap, Picasso.LoadedFrom from) {
        setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bitmap));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBitmapFailed(Drawable errorDrawable) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onPrepareLoad(Drawable placeHolderDrawable) {

    }
}
```

And

```
MyButton myButton = (MyButton) findViewById(R.id.btn);
Picasso.with(context).load("http://i.imgur.com/DvpvklR.png").into(myButton);
```